# Why does this SELECT ... IN statement not work?

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables in my database, with identical structures, SOURCE and TARGET.

The foreign key I'm using to join the two is the column 'email'.

Basically, TARGET contains only a list of validated emails, which is a subset of the emails in SOURCE, which also contains other address data keyed off of email. I need to pull all the records from SOURCE that have valid emails. Simple, eh? Can't seem to get MySQL to do this...

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  email,
  firstname,
  lastname,
  address,
  city,
  state,
  zip,
  phone
FROM Source 
WHERE email IN
  (SELECT email FROM Target);
```

When I do this, I get zero records; yet I know that `SELECT email FROM Target` works, and I know that SOURCE contains the emails.

I'm trying to do this in MySQL Workbench 5.2.34, where the query runs with no errors...but produces no output. (And I know the server is running, etc.)

Comment: Can you post sample email data from Target and Source table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works just fine. Without seeing any data it's impossible to say what's causing the issue, but there may be other problems that you're not showing us.

Working fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d505/1

The Schema:

```
Create table Source(
  email varchar(30),
  firstname varchar(30),
  lastname varchar(30),
  address varchar(30)
);

Create table Target(
  email varchar(30)
);


Insert into Source (email, firstname, lastname, address) VALUES('jack@gmail.com', 'jack', 'smith', '123 pine lane');
Insert into Source (email, firstname, lastname, address) VALUES('fake@gmail.com', 'fake', 'name', '456 pine street');

Insert into Target (email) VALUES('jack@gmail.com');
```

The Query:

```
SELECT
  email,
  firstname,
  lastname,
  address
FROM Source 
WHERE email IN
  (SELECT email FROM Target);
```

The Result:

```
jack@gmail.com  jack    smith   123 pine lane
```

Comment: What is the difference with using `IN` like OP post?

Comment: @IswantoSan Honestly, in this sense I think it's just more of a 'best practice' / personal preference to go with the JOIN.

Comment: Better to prefix columns with the table to prevent ambiguity.

Comment: I tried the INNER JOIN approach, with aliased table prefixes...still no joy. I think MySQL is getting confused with equating the emails...will try putting TRIM around them...thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Hmmm....this still doesn't work: INNER JOIN Target ON
TRIM(Source.email) = TRIM(Target.email)...running out of ideas here!

Comment: @rixter Was that last comment a question or ... what's up?

Comment: ok, give us some sample data and I'll build a working example :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27748/discussion-between-evan-and-rixter)

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured this out...sorry for this red herring of a post: the problem was extra line feeds (\n) characters in the import file used to create the TARGET table. The TRIM function in MySQL does not do anything for that, but this was why the join would not work. Once I removed the extra line feeds in the import file, and reimported the table, voila! Code worked...